# msvc140.dll missing on compiled visual studio .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there a way I can avoid this error (and thus having to install visual c++) when compiling an executable on visual studio and executing it on another PC which doesn't have visual c++?

Maybe a compilation option in visual studio?

Comment: It's really a duplicate of this question with my old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367336/104458

Comment: It seems i've answered this question another time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253259/104458

Comment: You have to distribuite the correct VC++ redistruable package together with your application

Comment: The other PC can separately install the [VC++ runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) A one time thing.